# Конвертация кооординат longitute & latitude в КЛАДР адрес

Tags: google-maps-api, gps, геолокация

Нужно по координатам GPS (latitude and longitude) определить город и код КЛАДР соответсвенно.

Подобных карт (в смысле мапинг map) соотношения не нашел, чтобы можно было, используюя АПИ какое-то, получить код КЛАДР по координатам.

Есть ли возможность по координатам определить адрес КЛАДР? Или единственный вариант — искать по строке после определения города по координатам, через google API, например?

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, извините, но Вы не могли бы ткнуть носом, а то найти про КЛАДР ничего не могу

Comment: Он даже в вики прописан https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%94%D0%A0. Базы переводите в удобный для вас вид и используете. Или в гугле смотрите по слову КЛАДР онлайн сервисы.

Comment: Я по сервисам искал в первую очередь и вики читал, все понятно, но как получить по координатам объект КЛАДР я не нашел и до сих пор найти не могу

Comment: О_о. 1. Геокодер вам по координатам возвращает адрес; 2. По адресу вы в базе КЛАДР ищите то что вам надо.

Comment: Спасибо, просто мы не поняли дру друга. Я изначально уточнил,что вижу только 1 способ, только в 2 этапа искать КЛАДР, чтобы сразу по координатам КЛАДР достать так нельзя. Только поиск адреса в строковом виде и затем уже поиск по этому адресу КЛАДР

Comment: Чтобы получить координаты для всех адресов можно так же воспользоваться геокодером ;) 25000 запросов в сутки бесплатно с одного ip ;)